# Multiple logging items to log

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to build out logging to log to a log file on specified events. When a file gets zipped, unzipped, start and stop time etc. What is the best approach: using a logfile and logout statements?

```
import logging
logfile = "******************** " + origfilename + " ********************"
logfile_out.write(logfile)
```

Comment: You `import logging` but never use it.  Why?

Comment: This is someone else's hack to this program and I am trying to fix it. It works to get a log file but I dont want to hack through this. Any suggestions? My question is how to log every single instance. When I initially wrote the logging on this it didn't work and he replaced it with the log file lines

Comment: Rather than blaming others, try to post code which sort of makes sense.  The one you have posted imports a module it does not use, then writes to a file object it does not open.

Comment: That is why I am asking for some guidance. Can you give me some insight please

Comment: How about using `logging`?

Comment: Ok I have logging in place now with a formatter. My question is how do i get each instance that was a logfile and replace it with proper logging?